# FFmpeg returns negative PTS and DTS for first non key frame

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

We have some envelope of FFmpeg, that processes the video.
The tree first frames of video are: B -> B -> I as shown below:

[image]

PTS and DTS returns negative for first frame:

[image]

We have some code, that skips the frames that are below some timepoint (0 for first frame).
Is it possible to ask FFmpeg to start from first frame and not from first I frame?

Comment: I will glad to see your answer )

Comment: Use lavf option `avoid_negative_ts` with value `make_zero`.

Comment: @Gyan if you were to start with a bunch of packets... does that mean you end up with a bunch of packets with pts/dts of 0?

Comment: No, ffmpeg will examine the first packet and offset it to zero. Then apply that offset to following packets.

Comment: m_pFormatCtx->avoid_negative_ts = AVFMT_AVOID_NEG_TS_MAKE_ZERO; doesn't make sense...

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: I found that we modified AVContext::strat_time manualy, and set DTS of first video packet. The problem solved, when I set PTS of first valid packet as start_time;

Answer (score 0):

I found that we modified AVContext::strat_time manualy, and set value based on DTS of a first valid video packet. The problem solved, when I set value based on PTS of a first valid packet as a start_time.